# How spooling requires memory protection?

Tags: operating-system, multitasking, spool, multiprogramming

Memory protection is useful in single-user and multi-user systems. However, i thought what is the use of memory protection in non-multiprogramming systems, as there can be only 1 program in memory.

But, after googling i got something new, that spooling in non-multiprogramming can require memory protection. But i am unable to get any new information of why spooling requires memory protection ?

Is my understanding right or am i missing something ?

Comment: Memory protection also protects the **kernel** from disallowed user accesses.

Comment: Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: Do you actually mean "paging" (virtual memory)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, i thought what is the use of memory protection in
>   non-multiprogramming systems, as there can be only 1 program in
>   memory.

...and, in addition, an operating system with sensitive data. Without memory protection, the program could write criss-cross over the OS, destroy data structures randomly, and wreck the whole system.